# Video Codec Question

Tags: video, formatting, compatibility, codec

I am developing an android and iphone application that has an option to upload video to our EC2 to be viewed by other permitted users.  These users might be viewing the video on their droid, iphone, or online.  My writers are claiming they can not code the video so that it is viewable on iphone, android, mac (QT) and pc (WMA), regardless of the phone used to upload the video.  True?  Or is there any advice I can pass on to them in terms of formatting the video for cross platform compatibility...?

Answer (score 0):

If you encode the video using the MP4(h.264 codec) container it will be viewable on the Android, iPhone, and on Mac and PC using the latest Flash player.

Comment: Just make sure that you hint streaming on the file so that it can be read on all platforms.  The only platform that will give you trouble is BlackBerry.